What is the concept of permissions under security tab versus sharing tab?
I have a shared folder.
When I right click on it and click properties, then,
Under security tab I can see list of users.
Under sharing tab, under permissions I can see a list of users.
It looks like security tab refers to security when folder is accessed locally. Whereas the sharing tab permission are possibly related to who can access the shared folder.
But I wonder if a user is under security, but not under sharing permission; Or if user is under sharing permission, but not under security; Then what exactly is the net outcome? Is this like an AND or an OR ?

The security tab exists since the NTFS file system was implemented, which allows to set permission entries at file/folder level. Before NTFS, you could share files and set permissions to the shared folder (or shared drive), but not at the file level.
To shorten the rest of the story: best practice is to set share permissions simply to everyone:modify and the NTFS permissions to reflect what you want more granually. This should answer it. AND/Or cannot be answered that simply since there exist differences in certain cases.
